# Error creating blob-aware objects in a plone.app.testing layer

Tags: testing, plone

I am writing a test for my product on Plone 3.3.5 with plone.app.testing 3.0a1 and plone.tesing 3.0a2.
I have many test with a slow setup, and I am moving the setup code to a layer.
The code instantiates tens of Archetypes objects of my content type, that has a blob field that is causing me problems.

When the objects are created in a layer, the test fails with this error:

```
Unsupported: Storing Blobs in <ZODB.DemoStorage.DemoStorage instance at 0x979e84c> is not supported.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pinning ZODB3 solved this issue:

```
ZODB3 = 3.9.7
```

But this verion [is not supposed to work with Plone 3](http://plone.org/products/plone.app.blob/issues/22).

The best solution I found so far is running tests with ZODB3=3.9.7, and the daemon with ZODB3=3.8.3.

Comment: the ZODB 3.9 series isn't compatible with plone 3 from what I understand.